# Unable to save java object in Redis

Tags: java, redis, persistence

I was trying to run the following example in my machine:

> https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-data-redis-example/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new ClassPathResource("/spring/spring-config.xml").getPath());
RedisRepo redisRepo = (RedisRepo)context.getBean(“redisRepo");

        try{

            JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "x.x.x.x”);
            Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();

            System.out.println("Connected to Redis”);//connected to Redis
            System.out.println("server is running: "+jedis.ping());//PONG
            System.out.println("current keys are :"+jedis.keys(“*”));//[ ]

            Employee s = new Employee();
            s.setId(1);
            s.setName(“abc”);
            redisRepo.saveState(s);
            System.out.println("server is running: "+jedis.ping());//PONG
            System.out.println("Finding the One : "+redisRepo.getState(1);//Finding the one :null

            }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
}
```

But getting the following error while trying to save the model object:

```
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

I would like to add that I can test the connection to redis server by pinging.How can I resolve this issue to persist data in Redis?

Comment: Please include the relevant code here directly.

Comment: can you be able to connect to client using console. ie., ./redis-cli?

Comment: @KarthikeyanGopall should i install redis locally on my machine?I did not try that command

Comment: Yes I am able to connect to client through redis-cli

Comment: try replacing "x.x.x.x” with "localhost" if redis is running in your local machine

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.How useful is it to save data in local instance than remote instance of redis server.Because I want to save data on " x.x.x.x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue to save data on local instance by running redis locally.While to save data on remote server I had import resource in the main class.Like:

> @ImportResource({classpath:path-to-youXML})